# Guardar datos de formualrio en un array

Tags: javascript, html, web, formularios

quiero registrar usuarios, no me quiere añadir los datos al array, los elementos del id son cajas de texto o textfields. Mi proyecto es sin base de datos.

```
var usuarios=["hola"];
var contraseñas=["1234"];

function registrarse()
{
    var nuevoUsuario=document.getElementById("usuario").value;
    var contraseña1=document.getElementById("contra").value;
    var contraseña2=document.getElementById("contra2").value;

    if(contraseña1 == contraseña2)
    {
        usuarios.push(nuevoUsuario);
        contraseñas.push(contraseña1);
        alert("Te has registrado exitosamente.");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("¡Las contraseñas no coinciden!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Donde estas llamando a tu funcion?

Comment: en un boton, con onclick

Comment: no veo porque no te los agregaria, hay algun error en la consola?

Comment: Mira aqui -> https://jsfiddle.net/b5a78hju/

Comment: El código esta bien, los  `console.log(usuarios); console.log(contraseñas);` tambien muestran las listas con sus valores... ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: No  sé  si será el problema que tienes o quizás lo vas  a  tener. Cuando recarguen la pagina o  pases a otra y luego regrees tu  array solo  contendrá a "Hola" y "123", lo demas lo pierdes. Si quieres conservarlos tendrás que  guardarlos en  una variable  de  sesión  cada vez  que registres un usuario. Al ingresar  a la pagina cargas tu array desde la variable de  sesion primero. Total  la  seguridad no debe ser muy  importante  por  la forma  en  que  lo estas haciendo.

Comment: como hago eso??